# How can I restart a service designed to run under supervise

Tags: automation

I have written a service designed to run under daemontools supervise.

Because the run script refreshes a source code repository:

```
   git pull
   pod_server  # serve up docs on source code via the web
```

I desire for the script to restart every 5 minutes.

The [manpage for svc](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svc.html) says that it applies all options to the service, so I thought this would work in cron:

*/5 * * * * svc -du etc/pod_server

but it does not seem to be refreshing to source code repo with new pushes

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used daemontools, but try separating the -d and -u (`svc -d ... ; sleep 5 ; svc -u ...`).

Also note that if the daemon your service doesn't respect the `TERM` signal (what -d sends by default) you can try `svc -k` to send KILL instead.  If I remember right the supervise daemon will then see that the service is down and restart it on its own.